# Sending HEX with socket->write in C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, tcp

I am writing a TCP console in C++ QT, I want to send Hex byte :  00 00 00 00 00 06 01 02 00 01 00 01    using socket->write(???),     where socket = new QTcpSocket(this)

To send Hex code  00 00 00 00 00 06 01 02 00 01 00 01, what shall be the format?
Thanks

Comment: Create a char buffer of size 12 and fill in contents like `char buf[12] = {0x00, 0x06, ...};` use this buffer in write().

Comment: That is what QByteArray is for. Also note that hex is just a representation for humans, which is typically used to render binary data. Do not confuse the two.

Comment: @kiner_shah I believe if they mentioned "hex" is because they want the ascii version.

Comment: I coded like : 
        char message[12] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01};

    socket->write(message);
It is connected, but no bytewritten signal emit....
No response also...

Comment: Have you checked whether an [error occured](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#errorString)? Is the socket opened/connected before trying to write?